# I want to get a count of how many rows there are for each minute in excel

Tags: excel

I want to get a count of how many rows there are for each minute.

So for 8/1/2008 2:40 there would be 7, 8/1/2008 2:41 would have 3, and 8/1/2008 2:42 would have 5

Comment: Can you explain why `8/1/2008 2:40 there would be 7`?

Comment: Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

[image: Excel pivot table]

Create a pivot table with the datetime as the row. Add the datetime as the data too, but check that it is using count.

Comment: @Fahad, Did you try this? Did it work. we would appreciate it if you could vote and select the correct answer to help people in the future to find correct anwers